# TinyMCE editor in Iframe and get value using Jquery

Tags: iframe, tinymce

i have a .html page

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="TinyMCScripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="TinyMCScripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe id="EditorFrame" src="UploadTemplates.aspx" frameborder="0" style="height: 551px;
            width: 794px"></iframe>
        <br />
        <p>
            <textarea id="TemplateEditor1" cols="50" rows="15">
            </textarea>
        </p>
        <input id="SaveTemplate" type="button" value="Save" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and i have a server side page called UploadTemplates.aspx which is the src of iframe and the MARKUP of UploadTemplates.aspx page is

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="TinyMCScripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="TinyMCScripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <div>
        <p>
            <textarea id="TemplateEditor" cols="50" rows="15" runat="server" class="tinymce">
            </textarea>
        </p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

now my question is that how can i get vlaue on my html page of Tiny Editor using jquery which is placed on another page called UploadTemplate.aspx please help

Answer (score 0):

If you got two separate pages you will need to do an ajax request to regulary save the editors content and deliver the saved content back on ajax response,

Comment: where would i save the Editor content? and when will be the ajax request called on editor?

Comment: well, to answer this you will have do describe what you want a bit more clearly

Comment: i have to get the Editor content and save it in to database. in above my code i have an html button called SaveTemplate and i want to get the editor value from an iframe on the  click of the SaveTemplate button by using jquery and then save the value to database. i just need to get the editor value first please help if you can dear.

Comment: this is pretty simple: using tinymce.get('my_editor_id').save() writes the editor content to the underlying object (a textarea for example). the other way to get the content is more direct: tinymce.get('my_editor_id').getContent();

Comment: sorry dear its doing nothing.i remind you that my editor is in iframe and the button is outside the iframe and i have to get the editor value outside the iframe

Comment: i wrote this tinymce.get("TemplateEditor").getCOntent() but nothing happend

Comment: use tinymce.get("TemplateEditor").getContent()